# Simple C question

Tags: c, file-io

HI all. I am trying to  make little program that reads data from file which has name of user and some data for that user. I am new on C , and how can i calculate this data for its user?line by line reading and adding each char in array? And how can I read line? is there any function?

And how can I use this each line users like object?I will make calculation for specific user.

Comment: Did you google "readline"?  You'll see reference to "fgets".  Perhaps you should start there.  You can then update your question to be more specific after you've read a little.  Right now, your question's hard to answer.

Comment: I tried "C readline from file" on Google, got many good results. Here's the first hit: http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet216411.html

Comment: Actually my question how can use this each  user like an object.

Comment: @Meko: No objects in C, but you can use a struct to hold the user name and the data for tha associated user. You could then make an array or linked list of these structs.

Comment: Maybe you should try consulting a C text book or tutorial? Maybe have a look at [C IO Functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fgets` to read a line at a time from the file.

Then you can parse the fields out and add them to an array or some other data structure. Just keep in mind if you use an array then you need to know ahead of time how many entries the file may contain - for example, no more than 1000. Otherwise you will need to use a data structure that can dynamically allocate memory such as a linked list, vector, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this site, i often use it for reference.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html

Play around with file i/o and get use to the functions and then you will be able to make what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is in [stdio.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/). (Link is to a C++ website but the entire C i/o system is usable in C++; hence the documentation)